# Convert non typical json string to JSON

Tags: performance, javascript-objects

I'm fetching from a random API url and I'm getting a response like this one:
`"key='jio3298', age=24, key='oijf032', age=62"`. ***How can I turn this non-json string into a list of JSON objects*** (i.e `[{'key': 'jio3298', age: 24}, {'key':'oijf032', 'age':62}]`) in an efficient way using JavaScript? I did get this code problem in an interview (one of the part of the problem. I needed that list to loop and filter based on a condition) and it seems my answer was at the very least slow.

Comment: Do you actually need it as JSON, or as JavaScript objects you can work with? Those aren't the same thing! Also, you mention you have some existing code - people will probably be happier to help you improve that (maybe on https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?) than to do the work for you

Answer (score 1):

you should use

> String.prototype.split()

to create an array and then loop on this arry and create pears of key and value.

**here an expmple:**

```js
const parser = (input) => {
  input = input.split(",");
  let keyAgeList = [],
    output = [];
  for (let i of input) {
    i = i.replace("'", "");
    i = i.replace(" ", "");
    i = i.split("=");
    if (i[0] === "key") {
      keyAgeList[0] = i[1];
    } else {
      keyAgeList[1] = i[1];
    }
    if (keyAgeList.length > 1) {
      let x = {
        key: keyAgeList[0].replace("'", ""),
        age: keyAgeList[1].replace("'", ""),
      };
      output.push(x);
      keyAgeList = [];
    }
  }
console.log(JSON.stringify(output))

  return JSON.stringify(output);
};
parser("key='jio3298', age=24, key='oijf032', age=62")
```